# Gatsby - Bootstrap Error: util.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4, gatsby, react-helmet

I am currently building a site in React using Gatsby framework. The following issue is this:

[image: Bootstrap error]

```
util.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:68
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

This error is thrown on this certain part (on Bootstrap tabs):

[image: Bootstrap tabs]

They don't work when pressed.

They do work however on a already live site (the same one I am making right now, but built with HTML/JS)

Fixes/"workarounds" I tried:

- Loading **jQuery** before other scripts. This is the order I am loading my scripts at (and stylesheets, just in case). They are loaded in using **React Helmet**. I also use this same order of loading scripts in HTML version:

```css
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" />

<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>

<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
/>
```

- Using different versions of jQuery and Bootstrap but it still doesn't work.

**Also**, one of the interesting behaviours is that it **sometimes works, sometimes doesn't**. It can happen when refreshing the page multiple times. It would work for couple of refreshes, then it would break and stay like that for couple of refreshes etc.

Comment: '*sometimes works, sometimes doesn't*' in this case it sounds like the problem is due to caching and/or a race condition somewhere. Without seeing a more complete example of your code we can't really offer any further diagnosis

Comment: I can post the whole code from a document where I load them. Would that be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend changing the approach. You are using React to create a virtual DOM (vDOM) to avoid/reduce high-performance actions (like jQuery does) pointing directly to the DOM. In addition, you are loading third-party dependencies outside the scope of React, since you are using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and not [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

> **Also**, one of the interesting behaviours is that it **sometimes works,
> sometimes doesn't**. It can happen when refreshing the page multiple
> times. It would work for couple of refreshes, then it would break and
> stay like that for couple of refreshes etc.

Your approach will always cause this behavior/issue, React will always be affected on third-party dependencies and will behave oddly depending on if they are loaded or not. In addition, loading jQuery, which as I said, points and manipulates the DOM, while React manipulates the vDOM may break the [React's hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/), potentially breaking your application, as it does.

Said that, the solutions are to avoid using jQuery (which personally I will always recommend). Everything that is coded in jQuery pointing the DOM, can be transpiled in vanilla JavaScript or using a React-friendly approach.

On the Bootstrap side, I would recommend using npm/yarn to handle the dependency and using a React'-based approach, like I said, using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). For example:

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough reply. I actually thought about using React Bootstrap but I saw that I would have to change a lot of things (for example, I would have to create <Tabs> component for the tabs in question) so I tried going with this route instead.

Comment: I get your point, but the caveats of using an outside dependency (old-fashioned, like jQuery) in new technology like Gatsby and React are, may force you to redo some parts because of the intrinsic behavior of the code

Answer (score 0):

Error is caused by bootstrap.js when it tries to access a jQuery fn property `$.fn`.
Best Solution is to make sure scripts are loaded in order.
Following Worked for me:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let scripts = [
      "/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
      "/assets/js/popper.min.js",
      "/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "/assets/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js",
      "/assets/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
      "/assets/js/inspinia.js",
      "/assets/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js",
    ];

    let current = 0;
    const max = scripts.length-1;

    let load_next_script = () => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('src', scripts[current]);
      script.setAttribute('defer', '');

      current++;
      if (current <= max){
        script.onload = load_next_script;
      }

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    load_next_script();
  });
```

I used it while converting a html-css-js-bootstrap template to ReactJS.